# Red5: Authentication - should i perform it in connect method?

Tags: authentication, red5

Should I perform authentication in connect method or should I create a separate method called `authenticate` that clients can then call to authenticate themselves? note that I’ll have to connect to a mysql database to perform authentication so it might take some time doing the I/O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you extend ApplicationLifecycle and place your authentication logic within the appConnect method. I've used this method on several projects and it works very well. Authentication tutorial (with source): http://blog.infrared5.com/2012/05/red5-authentication/

Comment: ApplicationLifecycle? can’t find that class (may be I am on an old version of Red5), I have ApplicationAdapter and MultithreadedApplicationAdapter

Comment: Not sure but I think Dominick created it when we started 1.0 dev.

Comment: Here's a direct link to the current source http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/server/trunk/src/org/red5/server/adapter/ApplicationLifecycle.java

Comment: Thank you, I am indeed on the older version. I have not tested your suggestion but I hope it would work :-)